# JavaFX: Why does FilteredList not implemented add()?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using a FilteredList, but it does not work as I expected.

The initialization is look like that:

```
listViewItems = new FilteredList<>(items);
```

My operation is like that:

```
listViewItems.add(new Object());
```

And it throws me a UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: The reason is doesn't let you do that is that `listViewItems` is supposed to *always* contain a subset of `items` (with the subset being defined by the predicate on the filtered list). If you could add a new item directly to `listViewItems`, that would no longer be true. Add it to `items` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `FilteredList` is a wrapper around a source list. As it is only a partial view of the real list, it cannot be modified.

EDIT: You can modify the underlying list by using `getSource()` to access it and then calling `add()` or `remove()`. The `FilteredList` will then automatically reflect the new state of the source list.